# iPhone doesn't automatically get inbox' child folder mail

Tags: iphone, mail.app, email

I have the following folder structure on my mail account

```
INBOX
    folder1
    folder2
SENT
...
```

My iPhone (7plus - latest os) does only retrieve messages that are put into `INBOX` by my mail server, the mails going to `folder1`, `folder2` aren't synced automatically and I will receive them only after I manually entered them inside the Mail app and do a manual refresh of the folder.

I would need to automatically receive those messages too, but couldn't find an option to do so.

Is it possible to sync folders automatically that are not `INBOX`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to pick folders to push if you want to sync certain sub-folders for notifications. To do this, go to Settings > Email > Accounts > Fetch new data > iCloud, and choose which folders should be pushed automatically.

I'm using a free app called 'myMail' that lets me choose the sub-folder to get the notification when there is new e-mail. It's working perfectly with my Gmail, Hotmail and IMAP account that has around 10 sub-folders. You can try it too.